# Image reflection styles?

Tags: css

I would like to produce a slight reflection on the two Hyperlink images i have embedded within div tags. What styles would I have to use? Any good links would be great too
Thanks

```
 <div class="paneStyle">
 <asp:Label ID="followUs" runat="server" Text="Follow us on:"  CssClass="followUsStyle"></asp:Label><br style="line-height:30px;"/>

 **<div id="FB" class="IconStyle"><asp:HyperLink ID="facebook" runat="server"   ImageUrl="/_layouts/Facebook.png"  NavigateUrl="http://www.........w"></asp:HyperLink></div>
 <div id="TW" class="IconStyle"><asp:HyperLink ID="twitter" runat="server"  ImageUrl="/_layouts/Twitter.png" NavigateUrl ="http:........"></asp:HyperLink></div>&nbsp**

 </div>
```